# IF and ELSE IF code help - Batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file

i just need a help on the if condition in the below sample batch script code, how do I implement an if and else if condition? if else doesnt recognize in my .bat file when running inw windows command:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // constant variables
set "_ROOT=%~dp0." & rem // (common root directory; `%~dp0.` is script's parent, `.` is current)
set "_DIR1=%_ROOT%\Directory1" & rem // (1st directory containing files)
set "_DIR2=%_ROOT%\Directory2" & rem // (2nd directory containing files)
set _MASKS="*INV*" "*SLS*"     & rem // (list of quoted file masks)
set "_TMP1=%TEMP%\%~n0_1_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (1st temporary file)
set "_TMP2=%TEMP%\%~n0_2_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (2nd temporary file)

rem // Resolve 1st directory to be an absolute path:
for %%E in ("%_DIR1%") do set "RDIR1=%%~fE"
rem // Resolve 2nd directory to be an absolute path:
for %%E in ("%_DIR2%") do set "RDIR2=%%~fE"

rem // Write all matching files in 1st directory to 1st temporary file:
pushd "%RDIR1%" && (
    for %%F in (%_MASKS%) do (
        echo(%%~nxF
    )
    popd
) > "%_TMP1%"
rem // Write all matching files in 2nd directory to 2nd temporary file:
pushd "%RDIR2%" && (
    for %%F in (%_MASKS%) do (
        echo(%%~nxF
    )
    popd
) > "%_TMP2%"

rem // Loop over all common files from both temporary files:
for /F %%L in ('findstr /L /I /X /G:"%_TMP1%" "%_TMP2%"') do (
    rem // Build absolute `wmic`-compatible file paths:
    set "FILE1=%RDIR1:\=\\%\\%%L" & set "FILE2=%RDIR2:\=\\%\\%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem set "FILE1=%!FILE1:&=&amp;!" & set "FILE2=%!FILE2:&=&amp;!"
    rem // Get standardised file date/time (last modification) of 1st file by `wmic`:
    for /F %%K in ('wmic DataFile where "Name='!FILE1!'" get LastModified') do set "DATE1=%%K"
    rem // Get standardised file date/time (last modification) of 2nd file by `wmic`:
    for /F %%K in ('wmic DataFile where "Name='!FILE2!'" get LastModified') do set "DATE2=%%K"
    rem // Compare file dates/times (last mod.) of both files and return differing ones:

    if !DATE1! gtr !DATE2! (echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is newer than "!FILE2:\\=\!")
   else if !DATE1! leq !DATE2! (echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is older than "!FILE2:\\=\!")
   else if !DATE1! equ !DATE2! (echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is same with  "!FILE2:\\=\!")


    endlocal
)

rem // Clean up temporary files:
del "%_TMP1%" "%_TMP2%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

This would be a very much help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `lss` instead of `leq`. So we will have *"less than"*, *"greater than"* and *"equal to"*, which seems to be what you want.

The correct method of using `else` in this instance would be:

```
if !DATE1! gtr !DATE2! (
     echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is newer than "!FILE2:\\=\!"
   ) else if !DATE1! lss !DATE2! (
          echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is older than "!FILE2:\\=\!"
    ) else if !DATE1! equ !DATE2! (
           echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is same with  "!FILE2:\\=\!"
)
```

**However**, We do not need `else` in this instance as each line will be evaluated until one returns true, so you could just do:

```
if !DATE1! gtr !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is newer than "!FILE2:\\=\!"
if !DATE1! lss !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is older than "!FILE2:\\=\!"
if !DATE1! equ !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is same with  "!FILE2:\\=\!"
```

I suggest you read the help, open `cmd.exe` and run:

- `if /?`

Comment: tried the new changes @Gerhard but it seems it shows output but there is a native error right now I am expecting DATE1 is greater than DATE2 but it shows that DATE1 and DATE2 are equal.

Comment: But echo the dates to see what they look like, please show me in your question

Comment: "DATE1=20190318040549.218407+480" and "DATE2=20190318095134.760320+480" @Gerhard

Comment: so this should be converted somewhere to fit the condition?

assumption: FFPDFINV06 in Directory1 which has DATE1 = 3/18/2019 2:47 PM and Directory2 has DATE2 = 3/18/2019 9:50 PM, it should expect output DATE2 is the newest file, not older, and not the same files.

Comment: Yes, so you need to make your conversion fit the scenario.